# What is a Contour plot (Matplotlib in Python) representing?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am confused about what my contour plot is representing. I have put the hardcoded value I obtained in my program for a *MWE* below. I have only 9 values (also plotted as scatter) but I don't understand how am I obtaining the diamond-shaped curves.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X =  np.array([[-1.62, -1.08, -0.54],
    [-1.62, -1.08, -0.54],
    [-1.62, -1.08, -0.54]])

Y = np.array([[2.16, 2.16, 2.16],
    [2.7 , 2.7 , 2.7 ],
    [3.24, 3.24, 3.24]])

Z= np.array([[1846.76519619, 1912.83024484, 1907.85033005, 1884.44377117,
    1936.11219261, 1917.34261408, 1864.70501227, 1909.25344747,
    1886.32844313]]).reshape(3,3)
plt.figure()
plt.title('Sample Contour Plot')
plt.gca().contour(X , Y , Z)
plt.scatter(X,Y,c=Z,s=20)

print('done')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The contour plot displays lines of constant value (sometimes called "isocontours"), which it gets through interpolation between your data points. If you add a colorbar then you can see the values that each contour line is referring to.

Internally, the code considers 4 points together (if the spacing were even then they will be a square) and performs an interpolation between the 4 values. The code does this for each of the groups of 4. Once complete, the levels are decided and the code uses the interpolated values to find where the contour levels exist. Because adjacent squares share an edge (and therefore two points), the contour lines will be continuous between squares. In your case, the middle point is the highest, so the contour lines loop around it. But because there are so few data points, the contour lines come out looking like a diamond shape (more points can result in a smoother contour line).

You can modify your code to add a colorbar with the contour line values.

```py
p = plt.contour(X, Y, Z)
plt.colorbar(p)
plt.scatter(X, Y, c=Z, s=20)
```

[image]

You might find it helpful to read the [Wikipedia page on contour lines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contour_line).

Comment: @JohanC With so little data there isn't really anything to see. Even with a 3D contour plot it's hard to see this data.

Comment: Thanks, I understand that each contour line represent a particular value. I am mainly interested in understanding how do they achieve the shape. There is a single point lying inside the central curve so, I am confused how did it achieve a closed diamond shape.

Comment: @skm I added more explanation. Does that clarify things?

Comment: @jared Super helpful, especially the diagram present on the Wikipedia page. Is there a way to create such a diagram for my data? 
Wikipedia diagram: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contour_line#/media/File:Courbe_niveau.svg